# duplicate a tab in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

When the user clicks on a button, I want to duplicate the current browser tab.

It's a react application with a router, so I first used `window.open('/')` and it works fine when the app is launched with a server.

But in my case, sometimes, the application is standalone and can be launched without any server, just an open file from the disk.

In this case, the '/' doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I could fix the issue with:

```
window.open(window.location.href);
```